# Angular 2 testing component html

Tags: unit-testing, angular, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to do angular2 tests and running into problems.  I am trying to test a binding in the HTML.  Briefly the code looks like this:

The component:

```
export class NavbarComponent {
    projectName = "Quiz!"
}
```

The template:

```
<a class="navbar-brand" routerLink="/intro">{{projectName}}</a>
```

I've been trying to follow examples online, ive tried the following ways of doing it:

```
describe('NavBar component', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [NavbarComponent],
        });
    });
});

it('should contain the projectName variable', () => {
    let fixture = TestBed.createComponent(NavbarComponent);
    fixture.detectChanges();

    let nav = fixture.nativeElement
    let title = nav.querySelectorAll('.navbar-brand');

    expect(title.textContent).toContain(nav.projectName);
});
```

That method gives this error: Error: Cannot create the component NavbarComponent as it was not imported into the testing module!

The second way I have tried:

```
let fixture: ComponentFixture<NavbarComponent>;
let component: NavbarComponent;
let debug: DebugElement;
let element: HTMLElement;

describe('NavBarComponent', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [NavbarComponent]
        });
    });

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(NavbarComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;

    debug = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.navbar-brand'));
    element = debug.nativeElement

});

describe('navbar title check, project name variable', function() {
    it('should be Quiz!', function () {
        fixture.detectChanges();
        expect(element.textContent).toContain(component.projectName);
    });
});
```

For this method, I get the following error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'detectChanges' of undefined

I am new to programming let alone testing, so any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: did you use import {NavbarComponent} from 'filepath'  inside your test file

Answer (score 0):

Put everything into the `describe`, and get rid of second `describe` and put the `it` inside first one. Also all your assignments should go inside the `beforeEach`

```
describe('', () => {
  let someVar;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({});
    someVar = whatever;
  })

  it('', () => {

  })
})
```

That should get you started.